# shared library relocation R_X86_64_PC32 error

Tags: c, linux, shared

I am trying to make 32 bit library on a 64 bit Ubuntu box. I am creating .so as follows

gcc - shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so *.o

I am getting  /usr/bin/ld : relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol "set_bright' cann't be used when making shared object;recompile with -fPIC.

Already I tried compiling with -fPIC. It didn't work.

Please let me know if I need to use any flag while compilation .c or some flag while creating .so

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you get that error if there you're calling a function declared as hidden, e.g.

```
int set_hidden(void) __attribute__((visibility("hidden")));
```

and it's not defined in the same shared object.

To solve it you have to also link the object file containing the definition of `set_hidden`, or remove the call to it.